# Trying to build a php form

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm trying to build a php form but it keeps erroring out and i'm not sure why.
Code

```
<?php

#Receive user input
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];

#Send email
$headers = "From: $email_address";
$sent = mail('enscivwy@gmail.com', 'Feedback Form Submission', $email_address, $headers);

#Thank user or notify them of a problem
if ($sent) {
  echo "thanks!";
} else {
  echo "something went wrong";
}
?>
```

the error is "something went wrong"

Comment: Can you describe more about the problem with your code? Alternatively, you can post error messages. Or at least describe exactly what you expect from your code. @Enscivwy

Comment: Instead of `echo "something went wrong"` use `error_get_last()['message']` ([PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#121163)). Tell us the error after that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: please post your HTML code which is calling this PHP .

Comment: I tried doing that @rojo, nothing appears

Comment: `mail()` is returning `false`. Most likely you don't have a mail server configured properly in PHP, or possibly haven't got one installed on your server.

Comment: What server hoster are you using?

Comment: BTW, you should use `htmlentities()` before sending mail wtih it.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a mail server setup in your system?

If you already have a mail server, then kindly let me know.

If you do not have a mail server, you can install various mail servers like [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), [Exim4](https://www.exim.org/) (more complicated, but more options for customization), etc.

My assumption is that you do not have a mail server.

To install postfix:

- Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install postfix`
- CentOS/Fedora: First: `sudo yum install epel-release`, and `sudo yum install postfix` or `sudo dnf install postfix`
- Arch Linux: `sudo pacman -S postfix`

---

**DO NOT USE BOTH OF THEM TOGETHER, ELSE YOU WILL GET INTO MORE PROBLEMS!**

---

To install exim4:

- Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install exim4`
- CentOS/Fedora: First: `sudo yum install epel-release`, and `sudo yum install exim` or `sudo dnf install exim`
- Arch Linux: `sudo pacman -S exim`

---

### Side note:

You can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead of the `mail()` function.

You have many features in [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) like using DKIM, sending with attachments, and better error debugging.